# Magic mouse 2 scrolling not working after installing windows 10

Tags: macbook-pro, mouse

I have installed windows 10 via boot camp. Now when i start up with windows , i can move magic mouse 2 on the screen but scrolling with mouse not working.
 When i start up with Osx 10.11.4 magic mouse 2 does not have problem.

Comment: Have you updated Bootcamp on the Windows side post-installation? You can do that by running Apple Software Update within Windows. Chances are the mouse requires new drivers that were not included in the support bundle used with the bootcamp install.

Comment: Masoud glad to hear it is working! I posted my answer below as well for the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend updating the Bootcamp application and drivers through Windows by using Apple Software Update. It is likely an outdated driver being on your system which does not have the proper information to handle the newer Magic Mouse 2.

Answer (score -1):

navigate to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Apple Software Update" and run the updates. You will be able to se the scroll feature.